# dotnet restore is taking too much time on gitlab-ci

Tags: .net, .net-core, gitlab-ci

I've set up a dotnet solution in Gitlab-CI for almost 6 months, and recently, job are slowing when pipelines are triggered.
From at most 5 minutes, my jobs are now failing due to timeout limitation of 1 hour.

I'd like diagnose the issue, but the verbosity in dotnet restore does not show significant information for me.

My CI config is as follows :

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

variables:
  PROJECT_NAME: "App"
before_script:
  - echo "starting build for $PROJECT_NAME"
  - echo "Restoring NuGet Packages..."
  - dotnet restore "$PROJECT_NAME.sln"

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cp src/Server/appsettings.json.default src/Server/appsettings.json
    - cp src/Server/appsettings.json.default src/Server/appsettings.Development.json
    - echo "Release build..."
    - dotnet build -v n "$PROJECT_NAME.sln"
  only:
    - Develop
```

The output of a job

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.1.0 (8925d9a0)
  on run_sentry.otr.lan qxRh1bkx

Preparing the "docker" executor
00:08
Using Docker executor with image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 ...
Pulling docker image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 ...
Using docker image sha256:6a9a891a94b307091a0366de4d0aa755b5cbf24204a5a25e7fe83322b607d491 for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 with digest mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk@sha256:23abf93a047e6f1bf1659bd0ff787facd6c80dcbf3421dd655f10bac209d1fde ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-qxrh1bkx-project-141-concurrent-0 via run_sentry.otr.lan...
Getting source from Git repository
00:04
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/dccfe/cadastre/front-end/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 61878ffe as feature/Opposition...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
59:47
Using docker image sha256:6a9a891a94b307091a0366de4d0aa755b5cbf24204a5a25e7fe83322b607d491 for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 with digest mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk@sha256:23abf93a047e6f1bf1659bd0ff787facd6c80dcbf3421dd655f10bac209d1fde ...
$ echo "starting build for $PROJECT_NAME"
starting build for Otr.Dccfe
$ echo "Restoring NuGet Packages..."
Restoring NuGet Packages...
$ dotnet restore "$PROJECT_NAME.sln"
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /builds/dccfe/cadastre/front-end/src/Shared/Shared.csproj (in 24.86 sec).
  Restored /builds/dccfe/cadastre/front-end/src/Domain/Domain.csproj (in 24.86 sec).
ERROR: Job failed: execution took longer than 1h0m0s seconds
```

Comment: The title says `dotnet restore` but the pipeline only ever runs `dotnet build` (which implicitly `restore`s). It seems like you have more information that you are not showing us. A buildlog for instance should show the part where the build is being slow.

Comment: Hi @GoodNightNerdPride, please kindly see the output I've just added. Thank you.

Comment: If I'm reading the output correctly then it isn't the build, but fetching the changes from git (i.e. something between the timestamps `00:04` and `59:47`) that takes so long, isn't it?

Comment: Your build pipeline has a total maximum of 60 minutes. It's not the dotnet restore that is slow (only takes 24 secs), but your git initialization takes way too long.

Comment: Thank you all. I have a before script section that's actually trying to restore the projects of my solution. @Marnix, if it's the Git initialization that's taking that much time, how can I solve this ?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride, it's the 'Executing step_script stage of the job script' that is for `59:47`, and that duration is provided after the is executed.

Comment: But the output of the `befores_script` can clearly be seen _after_ the `59:47` timestamp. I really don't see how you make the connection that dotnet restore is taking too long.

Comment: You can see the last command executed `dotnet restore "$PROJECT_NAME.sln"` that restored only 2/8 projects of the solution. The `57:47` timestamp tells the duration of the section, and this covers the `dotnet restore` command.

Comment: You will have to give us some more info about the size of your repository. In [this ticket](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/ci-takes-too-much-time-get-repo-with-git-fetch/35030) they play with the GIT_DEPTH. But it really depends on the size of your repo. Perhaps you can set it to a shallow clone, because you don't need the whole history, just an export of the current state

Comment: Hi all, after oberving my jobs for a while, I remark that the duration is becoming acceptable (15 min almost). I'll keep monitoring to know clearly what's the problem. Thank you all.